# Values Are Undefined though array is populated with values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why The Values Are Undefined though array is populated with values.
Though the values are there why it is displaying undefined.

```js
var app= angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myController',function($scope){
  $scope.city=['Odisha','Hyderabad'];
});
```

```css
div{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<htmL>
  <head>
    <title>Movie Ticket Booking</title>
  </head>
  
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
      Choose City:<select ng-model="cities" ng-change="changeCity()" ng-options="items for item in city"></select>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Try `item for item in city`, not `items for item in city`

Comment: thanks quiet new to this language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `item` instead of `items`

```js
var app= angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myController',function($scope){
  $scope.city=['Odisha','Hyderabad'];
});
```

```css
div{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<htmL>
  <head>
    <title>Movie Ticket Booking</title>
  </head>
  
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
      Choose City:<select ng-model="cities" ng-change="changeCity()" ng-options="item for item in city track by item"></select>
    </div>
    <div>{{cities}}</div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution

```js
var app= angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myController',function($scope){
  $scope.city=['Odisha','Hyderabad'];

  $scope.changeCity=function(){
     alert($scope.selectedName)
  }
});
```

```css
div{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<htmL>
  <head>
    <title>Movie Ticket Booking</title>
  </head>
  
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
      Choose City:<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-change="changeCity()" ng-options="item for item in city"></select>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.